# animation color sass with variables not working

Tags: sass, css-animations

I want to select the color depend of class. But it always takes the last values in the $color1 and $color2 variables. So it is always showed as yellow.

```
.animated-color {
  -webkit-animation: color_change var(--time-color) infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: color_change var(--time-color) infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: color_change var(--time-color) infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: color_change var(--time-color) infinite alternate;
  animation: color_change var(--time-color) infinite alternate;
}

.color-white {
  $color1: white;
  $color2: white;
  @-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-o-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
}

.color-yellow {
  $color1: rgb(255, 253, 137);
  $color2: rgb(255, 254, 168);
  @-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @-o-keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
  @keyframes color_change {
    from {
      background-color: $color1;
    }
    to {
      background-color: $color2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are expecting by defining `@keyframes` inside other selectors. Once compiled, what you get here is two `@keyframes` both named `color_change`. And since the last one defined in your code has the yellow colors, it is the one used when you call it with `animation`.

Comment: I want to be available to have two different animation colors with differents colors.

Comment: Then you should make two different keyframes (different name).

Comment: Thank you so much @Arkellys